# How does the Flyweight pattern in Java work with respect to memory management?

Tags: java, design-patterns, flyweight-pattern

I feel like I have an ok grasp on the design pattern, however I can't seem to get my head around one thing and it doesn't seem to be exactly explained in the resources I've looked at.
That question is, ***how is the data common, without the data being static, considering the objects are separate entities?***

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/flyweight_pattern.htm

In this example, I cannot figure out where the optimisation is occurring, as it looks as if the objects are just being created each time as normal.

```
Circle circle = (Circle)ShapeFactory.getCircle(getRandomColor());
circle.setX(getRandomX());
circle.setY(getRandomY());
circle.setRadius(100);
circle.draw();
```

This code block seems like my best guess as the first line retrieves from the HashMap a circle with a certain colour, but this creates a new instance of a circle, with no lasting reference to the colour of the circle.
Therefore, unless I'm mistaken, there is no actual shared data, so I am unsure of how this provides benefits other than maybe during creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShapeFactory` in your linked example will create one `Circle` per color:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ShapeFactory {
   private static final HashMap<String, Shape> circleMap = new HashMap();

   public static Shape getCircle(String color) {
      Circle circle = (Circle)circleMap.get(color);

      if(circle == null) {
         circle = new Circle(color);
         circleMap.put(color, circle);
         System.out.println("Creating circle of color : " + color);
      }
      return circle;
   }
}
```

If no `Circle` with a specified color exists, it will create a new `Circle` object and store this instance in the `circleMap` hashmap. If a `Circle` with a specific color already exists, it will return the already existing instance from the `circleMap`.

This is also explained in the text:

> ShapeFactory has a HashMap of Circle having key as color of the Circle object. Whenever a request comes to create a circle of particular color to ShapeFactory, it checks the circle object in its HashMap, if object of Circle found, that object is returned otherwise a new object is created, stored in hashmap for future use, and returned to client.

This is also evident in the output shown in the tutorial:

```
Creating circle of color : Black
Circle: Draw() [Color : Black, x : 36, y :71, radius :100
Creating circle of color : Green
Circle: Draw() [Color : Green, x : 27, y :27, radius :100
Creating circle of color : White
Circle: Draw() [Color : White, x : 64, y :10, radius :100
Creating circle of color : Red
Circle: Draw() [Color : Red, x : 15, y :44, radius :100
Circle: Draw() [Color : Green, x : 19, y :10, radius :100
Circle: Draw() [Color : Green, x : 94, y :32, radius :100
Circle: Draw() [Color : White, x : 69, y :98, radius :100
```

Each colored `Circle` is only created once, but modified many times.

---

I agree that the tutorial doesn't really show the benefit of a Flyweight though. The main point of the flyweight is to externalise shared state. The usual examples I know use character properties in a document.

Instead of having one `Character` with `position`, `font`, `size` and `textDecoration`, you would externalize the latter three, thereby reducing the memory needed for each `Character` instance:

> This is some text.

In the line above, the individual characters would only need to store their position, but the formatting is the same, so that can be externalised to a single flyweight object.

> This is some **bold** text.

In the line above, you'd have two flyweights. One for the regular text and another for the four bold character instances.

Comment: I don't understand what benefit this gives you. The first line of the block in the OP has the circle created as a copy of the circle from the hashmap, which means each circle object is a different object. As such you would have multiple copies of the object that do not share any data and so are the same size in memory. Is it just a bad example of the pattern?

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure why you think it creates a copy? But it's certainly a bad example as the point of the flyweight is to externalise shared state and the flyweight objects themselves should be immutable Value Objects.

Comment: Never mind I'm dumb, I forgot that Java copies by reference

Comment: Do further reading on this, but it's best to think that Java copies by alias. By reference and by value both have different semantics that do not match Java's behaviour exactly.